# Longtable: Text appears where it should not appear

Tags: tables, floats, longtable, multirow

I am using the `longtable`environment for printing my large table on a landscape-page.

### Problem:

I have to use some `multirows`and this seems to corrupt the tabular-enironment
After breaking the page, the row which I merged appears in the header of the next table.

I am already using

> ```
> \usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
> ```

## MWE:

> ```
> \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{pdflscape}
> \usepackage{longtable}
> \usepackage{booktabs}
> \usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
> %%%FILL IN DUMMY VALUES%%%
> \newcounter{countA}%
> \newcommand{\numcols}{55}
> \newcommand{\numcolsminusfirst}{53}
> \newcommand{\repeatentry}[2]{%
> \def\myline{#1}%
> \setcounter{countA}{1}%
> \loop\ifnum\thecountA<#2%
>     \stepcounter{countA}%
>     \edef\myline{\myline & #1}%
> \repeat%
> \myline{}%
> }
> %%%FILL IN DUMMY VALUES%%%
> \begin{document}
> \begin{center}
> \begin{landscape}
> {\arraystretch}{.5}
> \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.8mm}
> \begin{longtable}{*{\numcols}{c}}
> \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
> \toprule
> \repeatentry{x}{\numcols}
> \\\midrule
> \endfirsthead
> \multicolumn{\numcols}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\
> \toprule
> \repeatentry{x}{\numcols}
> \\\midrule
> \endhead
> \hline \multicolumn{\numcols}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
> \endfoot
> \hline
> \endlastfoot
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \multirow{-3}{*}{Test}&\repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \repeatentry{-}{\numcolsminusfirst}\\
> \end{longtable}
> \end{landscape}
> \end{center}
> \end{document}
> ```

### Screenshot of MWE

[image: MWE]

Comment: Are you sure about `\usepackage[multirow]{longtable}`? I couldn't find any hint on an option called `multirow` in the `longtable` documentation.

Comment: You are right, i corrected this in my code, i meant `usepackage[longtable]multirow`

Comment: I doubt that you have to use multirow - I never had to -  but if you use it you should suppress pagebreaks in the relevant lines with `\\*`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i was not ware of this command, thank you. I tried it and this seems to solve the issue, So there is no other way of using `multicolumn` correct in combination with `longtable`?

Comment: Well it is what the documentation of multirow recommends - it even has a section about "use with longtable".

Comment: oh okay than i did not read carefully enough, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation of multirow writes

> However, care must be taken that the longtable doesn’t
>   break the multirow entry when it is near the bottom of the page.
>   [...] you want to prevent the pagebreak to occur in the middle of this entry. You can do
>   this by ending the intermediate rows with `\\*` instead of `\\`.

Comment: reading doc again, it'll never catch on

Comment: @DavidCarlisle to tell the truth I tried `\\*` first (as it was the obvious idea) and then checked if the documentation mentions it ;-).